# Same content over multiple sites

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have an account on wordpress. I am writing blogs there. Now I have published my same blogs with same content over DZONE and geekswithblogs.net and few other . Now my question is whether the SEO ranking of wordpress blogs will be hit. If yes then may I know how can I prevent that to happen if I post the same content over the other blogs publishing sites. Can I cross-link (by giving the original link of wordpress) on other sites, will that help me to prevent the SEO hit ? Any other suggestions will be so helpful. Should I stop posting over other sites and remain stick to my original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do is let Google know the original source of the content. If possible, do the following:

1) Use rel="canonical" on the republished articles linking to the original article

2) On the republished articles link back to the original article and cite it as the original source

**update**

3) There's also a new [Google meta tag](http://googlenewsblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/credit-where-credit-is-due.html) that may help as well

Comment: May I know how can I cite it as original source ? and can I write full same content in republished one what was there in the original one , I will provide a link(which will point to original) at the bottom of this republished one or I just have to write summary to prevent me from being penalized.

Comment: Linking to it is fine. Making sure your page has a date on it showing it was published after the original article so it will be easier to google to determine which came first. I also amended my answer with another meta tag that would be useful, too.

Comment: Will date be needed? I think Google will guess the date to be the date of it's indexing it automatically. Plenty of articles don't have dates in internet but still we can search those using filters..

Comment: Date isn't needed as far as I know. There isn't any reliable way to know when content was published.